# How long data can pass through intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know how long data can pass though intent. If i am passing parcelabel(as i am passing bitmap) more than 500x500 size it is give java transection binding fail.

Comment: you should never do that. pass the path of the image instead

Comment: Raghunandan is right. Send path of the image instead of the image itself.

Comment: @shree202 I done it but i want to know the limitation of intent

Answer (score 1):

If it's small (thumbnail) then it should be fine, if it is big you can end up with failed binder transaction errors. To avoid it you should pass a URI to location where it is saved. You can put it on sdcard if you have permission or in cache folder if not. If you are sending intent to some other process, then you should put bitmap on sdcard to make it readable by other processes. Last solution is to write Content Provider, this is usefull when you are sharing bitmap files, and want to for example attach bitmap with email.

Comment: I know this solution, but i want to know the limitation of intent

Comment: Dianne Hackborn sugests 100kb limit in this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-developers/TED_ZrCHmNo